# Set memory limit for a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

How to set RAM limit for a .bat file in Windows cmd?

I am trying to build my own contest managment system and I must know that the tested programs do not use odd memory.

Comment: You can't. What do you mean by odd memory?

Comment: @Seth, I mean that for each test (program execution with some params) program must use some amount of memory. As an example you need to sort an array and use not more than 1.5MB of RAM. If you will use more of it you will fail the test

Comment: I'm really not sure that a batch would be the best choice in this case. One possible approach would be to record the memory usage before executing the program (maybe using WMI) and somehow monitor the peak usage during the execution. If you actually want to kill a process depending on how much RAM is being used you could potentially use a similar approach. The downside is that you're ignoring any variables like update processes, child processes and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the memory usage of any given process. The problem is that process memory usage is controlled by the system memory manager and influenced by many factors, some of which are totally unrelated to what the process is doing. This would be the case for any modern OS.